# Assign column variables by date (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, date, sorting

I hope we're all doing great

I have several decades of daily rainfall data from several monitoring stations. The data all beings at separate dates. I have combined them into a single data frame with the date in the first column, with the rainfall depth in the second column. I want to sort the variable 'Total' by the variable: 'Date and time' (please see the links below)

```
ms1 <- read.csv('ms1.csv')
ms2 <- read.csv('ms2.csv')
```

etc.etc

```
df <- merge(ms1, ms2 etc. etc, by = "Date and Time")
```

The problem is that the range of dates would differ for each monitoring station (csv file). There may also missing dates in a range. Is there a way around this?

Would I have to create a separate vector with the greatest possible date range? Or would it automatically detect the earliest start date from the imported data.

> for monitoring station 1 (ms1)

[image]

> for monitoring station 2 (ms2)

[image]

Note: the data continues to the current date

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I wasn't sure how to do that